# ImportError: No module named 'PySide.QtCore' in python3.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x

I just upgraded my ubuntu to version 14.04, and since then `python3.3` cannot import `QtCore` when calling my script; the full error output is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcode.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PySide.QtCore import *
ImportError: No module named 'PySide.QtCore'
```

Interestingly, the modules seem to be present:

```
>ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PySide/
__init__.py                                    QtGui.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so      QtScriptTools.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  QtWebKit.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
phonon.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so         QtHelp.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so     QtSql.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so          QtXml.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
__pycache__                                    QtNetwork.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  QtSvg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so          QtXmlPatterns.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
QtCore.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so         QtOpenGL.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so   QtTest.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so         _utils.py
QtDeclarative.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  QtScript.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so   QtUiTools.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

The above path to `dist-packages` is included in `sys.path`. Any idea how to fix this import issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem seems to be the naming of the modules. `python` seems to look for a file named `QtCore.so` instead of `QtCore.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, for example. Creating symlinks like

```
sudo ln -s QtCore.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so QtCore.so
```

for each library seems to solve the problem.

However, the ideal way would be probably to remove `PySide` for `python3.3` and to re-install it fresh. But I do not know the naming convention to name the package to be removed...

Maybe someone knows the exact package identifier?